# Is there a Linux-native alternative to the CrystalDiskInfo daemon?

Tags: hard-drive, software-recommendation, services, monitoring, smart

On Windows, I use CrystalDiskInfo to tell me when a hard drive goes bad. It has an indicator icon and automatically updates the SMART-data every couple of minutes or so.

On Linux, there are programs to check SMART values, but they have to be executed manually.

Is there a program that runs in the background and sends a notification as soon as there's a SMART warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the command line, I did:

```
man -k smart
```

and, after ignoring the other meanings of "smart", got:

```
gsmartcontrol (1)    - Hard disk drive health inspection tool
gsmartcontrol-root (1) - Hard disk drive health inspection tool
smart-notifier (1)   - dbus service and graphical disk health notifier
smartctl (8)         - Control and Monitor Utility for SMART Disks
smartd (8)           - SMART Disk Monitoring Daemon
smartd.conf (5)      - SMART Disk Monitoring Daemon Configuration File
update-smart-drivedb (8) - update smartmontools drive database
```

These programs are in the following packages:

```
walt@bat:~(0)$ for i in \
    gsmartcontrol-root gsmartcontrol smart-notifier smartctl smartd \
    ; do \
        dpkg -S $(type -p $i); \
    done
gsmartcontrol: /usr/bin/gsmartcontrol-root
gsmartcontrol: /usr/bin/gsmartcontrol
smart-notifier: /usr/bin/smart-notifier
smartmontools: /usr/sbin/smartctl
smartmontools: /usr/sbin/smartd
```

Comment: I think smart-notifier is the best solution, thanks.